# Edit Additional Template in VS 2012 for windows 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-store-apps

II am developing a windows metro application,I want to edit tempalte for listview and listviewitem, from where I can do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

•To edit Listview in design mode, you may do it like this:

```
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

    lvi.Text = "Row1";

    lvi.SubItems.Add("11");

    lvi.SubItems.Add("aa");     



    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);





    lvi = new ListViewItem();

    lvi.Text = "Row2";

    lvi.SubItems.Add("21");

    lvi.SubItems.Add("bb");



    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
```

•
To edit ListView at runtime, 
If you're looking for "in-place" editing of a ListView's contents (specifically the subitems of a ListView in details view mode), you'll need to implement this yourself, or use a third-party control like:
 How to: Create a ListView with Editable Cells
 An Editable ListView

•
By default, the best you can achieve with a "standard" ListView is to set it's LabelEdit property to true to allow the user to edit the text of the first column of the ListView you need to custom draw(derive from current control).